# Figure and Listings Produce Extra Page Break

Tags: floats, listings, page-breaking

I am trying to include a tex file directly after a figure environment. When I do, the `listings` ends up being on the next page even though a large amount of space exist on the previous page. How do I prevent the page break from occurring?

MWE Split across two files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  caption           = {Missing Caption}
  ,label            = {lst:missingLabel}
  ,basicstyle       = \footnotesize\ttfamily 
  ,frame            = shadowbox
  ,numbers          = left
  ,breaklines       = true
  ,keywordstyle     = \color{darkgreen}
  ,commentstyle     = \color{red}
  ,tabsize          = 2
  ,backgroundcolor  = \color{lightgrey}
}

\begin{document}

\include{figureStandard.tex}

\lstinputlisting
  [ language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    caption={Standard Figure Environment},
    label={lst:figureStandard}
  ]{figureStandard.tex}

\end{document}
```

figureStandard.tex

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics 
    [width=0.8\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]
    {example-image-16x9}%{example-image-a}
  \caption 
    [Standard Figure Setup] 
    {Standard Figure Setup} 
  \label{fig:standard}
\end{figure}
```

P.S. - Not sure how to easily write to a file, otherwise the second file would be part of the MWE.

Comment: There is an automatic page break at the start and end of \include.  You can use \input instead.  See also \includeonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Jon Kormylo:
"There is an automatic page break at the start and end of \include. You can use \input instead. See also \includeonly."